# How to call dynamic URL in jquery function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events, jquery-countdown

How can I call URL after end of event time with each timer below? I pass all code of countdown. I need to find where I place URL, which will be hyperlink image after Timer display, after time ended picture show but with undefined URL link. where I declare this `variable = +match_link+` to show link after event:

```
var match_link = digits[elem].parent().parent().parent().children('.match-info').children('a:first-child').attr('href');
          digits[elem].parent().parent().html('<a href="'+match_link+'" class="live-now"><img width="145" height="35" src="http://files.barcelonastream.com/media-resources/other/WatchNow.png" class="attachment-medium" alt="WatchNow" title="WatchNow"></a>');
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
try{if (!window.CloudFlare) {var CloudFlare=[{verbose:0,p:0,byc:0,owlid:"cf",bag2:1,mirage2:0,oracle:0,paths:{cloudflare:"/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=1613a3a185/"},atok:"cc11de0e81b190b819ea8d9a1ae30b94",petok:"bebab39309d8af2d0876cf8ed34772ef3629ea6f-1443543175-1800",zone:"realmadridlive.in",rocket:"a",apps:{}}];document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=e9627cd26a/cloudflare.min.js"><'+'\/script>');}}catch(e){};
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketsrc="http://realmadridlive.in/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
 
jQuery.fn.countdown = function(userOptions)
{
  // Default options
  var options = {
    stepTime: 60,
    // startTime and format MUST follow the same format.
    // also you cannot specify a format unordered (e.g. hh:ss:mm is wrong)
    format: "dd:hh:mm:ss",
    eventTime: "Jan, 1, 2014, 00:00",
    digitImages: 6,
    digitWidth: 53,
    digitHeight: 77,
    timerEnd: function(){},
    image: "digits.png"
  };
  var digits = [], interval;
 
  userOptions.startTime = timeleft(userOptions.eventTime);
 
  // Draw digits in given container
  var createDigits = function(where)
  {
    var c = 0;
    var tempStartTime = options.startTime;
    // Iterate each startTime digit, if it is not a digit
    // we'll asume that it's a separator
    for (var i = 0; i < options.startTime.length; i++)
    {
      if (parseInt(tempStartTime.charAt(i)) >= 0)
      {
        elem = jQuery('<div id="cnt_' + i + '" class="cntDigit" />').css({
          height: options.digitHeight * options.digitImages * 10,
          float: 'left', background: 'url(\'' + options.image + '\')',
          width: options.digitWidth});
        digits.push(elem);
        margin(c, -((parseInt(tempStartTime.charAt(i)) * options.digitHeight *
                              options.digitImages)));
        digits[c].__max = 9;
        // Add max digits, for example, first digit of minutes (mm) has
        // a max of 5. Conditional max is used when the left digit has reach
        // the max. For example second "hours" digit has a conditional max of 3                
 
        switch (options.format.charAt(i)) {
          case 'h':
            digits[c].__max = (c % 2 == 0) ? 2: 9;
            if (c % 2 != 0)
              digits[c].__condmax = 3;
            break;
          case 'd':
            digits[c].__max = 9;
            break;
          case 'm':
          case 's':
            digits[c].__max = (c % 2 == 0) ? 5: 9;
        }
        ++c;
      }
      else
        elem = jQuery('<div class="cntSeparator"/>').css({float: 'left'})
                .text(tempStartTime.charAt(i));
                               
                        where.append('<div>');
                        where.append(elem);
                        where.append('</div>');
    }
  };
 
  // Set or get element margin
  var margin = function(elem, val)
  {
    if (val !== undefined)
      return digits[elem].css({'marginTop': val + 'px'});
 
    return parseInt(digits[elem].css('marginTop').replace('px', ''));
  };
 
  // Makes the movement. This is done by "digitImages" steps.
  var moveStep = function(elem)
  {
    digits[elem]._digitInitial = -(digits[elem].__max * options.digitHeight * options.digitImages);
    return function _move() {
      mtop = margin(elem) + options.digitHeight;
      if (mtop == options.digitHeight) {
        margin(elem, digits[elem]._digitInitial);
        if (elem > 0) moveStep(elem - 1)();
        else
        {
          clearInterval(interval);
          for (var i=0; i < digits.length; i++) margin(i, 0);
          options.timerEnd();
          var match_link = digits[elem].parent().parent().parent().children('.match-info').children('a:first-child').attr('href');
          digits[elem].parent().parent().html('<a href="'+match_link+'" class="live-now"><img width="145" height="35" src="http://files.barcelonastream.com/media-resources/other/WatchNow.png" class="attachment-medium" alt="WatchNow" title="WatchNow"></a>');
 
          return;
        }
        if ((elem > 0) && (digits[elem].__condmax !== undefined) &&
            (digits[elem - 1]._digitInitial == margin(elem - 1)))
          margin(elem, -(digits[elem].__condmax * options.digitHeight * options.digitImages));
        return;
      }
 
      margin(elem, mtop);
      if (margin(elem) / options.digitHeight % options.digitImages != 0)
        setTimeout(_move, options.stepTime);
 
      if (mtop == 0) digits[elem].__ismax = true;
    }
  };
 
  jQuery.extend(options, userOptions);
  this.css({height: options.digitHeight, overflow: 'hidden'});
  createDigits(this);
  interval = setInterval(moveStep(digits.length - 1), 1000);
};
 
function timeleft(eventTime) {
        var now = new Date();
        var now_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
        var event_time = new Date(eventTime);
       
       
        var t1 = now_utc.getTime();
        //removes one hour from the date - 60 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 miliseconds - -60*60*1000
        var t2 = event_time.getTime();
        var time_left = new Date(parseInt(t2-t1));
        if(time_left<0) {
                return "00:00:00:00";
        }
        msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        days = Math.floor(time_left/msPerDay);
        if (days < 10) { days = "0"+days; }
        hours = time_left.getUTCHours();
        if (hours < 10) { hours = "0"+hours;}
        minutes = time_left.getUTCMinutes();
        if (minutes < 10) { minutes = "0"+minutes; }
        seconds = time_left.getUTCSeconds();
        if (seconds < 10) { seconds = "0"+seconds; }
       
        return(days+":"+hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="sct_id_0" class="simple_countdown_timer" style="width: 150px; margin: auto;">
<div class="sct_count" style="height: 19px; vertical-align: middle; overflow: hidden;"></div>
<div class="desc c1">
<div>days</div>
<div>hours</div>
<div>min</div>
<div class="secs">sec</div>

<script type="text/rocketscript">
jQuery(function(){
 jQuery('#sct_id_0 .sct_count').countdown({
  image: 'http://i.imgur.com/4Xw40YA.png',
  format: "dd:hh:mm:ss",
  // Jan,19,2015,16:00
  eventTime: "Sep,29,2015,18:45",
  digitWidth: 13,
  digitHeight: 19,
 });
});
</script></div>
  
</div>
  Script code Not working in stackoverflow so i iframe this script 
  
  <iframe src="http://realmadridlive.in/mrk-schedule.php" /></iframe>
  
  
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you right, you may use .html function
https://jsfiddle.net/3ws247hh/

```
$('#sct_id_0').html("<img src='http://findicons.com/icon/download/169459/alert/128/png' /> ")
```

Comment: actually it for one event but i use it multiple events so may b it will work on 1 event but not more